How Can I Efficiently Structure a Data Model for Handling Both One-Time and Recurring Tasks in a Task Management app?
fellow developers and architects! I'm in the process of designing a webapp aimed at managing tasks and recurring tasks, which can be seen as habits. The unique challenge I'm facing revolves around how to best structure my data model to efficiently handle both one-time tasks and recurring tasks, without differentiating between them during data retrieval.
The current design splits the "task" concept into two entities:

Task: Holds shared task data such as title, description, category, type, recurrence rule, etc.
State: Contains specific instance data like state (new, in-progress, done), start date, due date, etc.

This structure necessitates that both tables/entities be joined and fetched together at all times, considering that task entity attributes (like description and title) are often updated.
To provide more context, here are a few use cases to consider:
Usecase1: Imagine a calendar monthly view, and today is January 1st, with each user having hundreds of tasks, each with recurrences many times a week. The user wants to see all the tasks they have to do in the following December and change the due date/time of some of them.
Usecase2: With the same setup as above, a user has a task with a daily recurrence. They now want to change the recurrence to every second day and change the due time.
Usecase3: Again, the same calendar setup, but now the user wants to change the description and title of some tasks on a regular basis. Of course, this change should apply to every single recurrence of that particular task.
Given these requirements, I have several questions for the community:

Performance & Scalability: What are your thoughts on the proposed data model in terms of performance and scalability?
Database Selection: Which type of database would be best suited for this application (SQL vs. NoSQL) and why?
Alternative Models: Are there more efficient data models or structures that could handle these scenarios better?
State Entity Creation: For recurring tasks, should "state" entities be generated in advance or on-demand? How can this be optimized for both the user experience and system performance?
Considering the data model I described, how and when should the “state” entities be created for a task? In advance? On demand? If I create state entities in advance, I risk that the user picks a time frame where those states are still missing, so I have to make a check anyway if new state entities need to be created. On the other hand, if I do it on demand it will make all the queries very slow as with each fetch operation I first need to check and if needed to create the state entities.

Your insights, especially if you've tackled similar challenges, would be invaluable to me. I'm particularly interested in any architectural advice, design patterns, or technology recommendations that could enhance the app's functionality and user experience.

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! This question is very broad for a Q&A format. Schema design is an iterative process - you need to design, code, test, loop. Googling (did you try this?) the terms database schema for recurring tasks and https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=open+source+scheduling+software+recurring+tasks gave me several interesting links. Do that, start coding and come back to us with more specific questions.

I wouldn't assume there is a single solution to the general problem of appointment/task calendars.
With appointments that form a linked series, these might be either on a completely ad-hoc schedule, or they might be periodic according to some established calendar.
The definition of calendars itself can be complicated - for example, a common one in use is "the first/last working day of the month".
Where the series follows a calendar, they may follow it strictly, or they may occasionally deviate.
And the entire series may be planned out at the outset, or it may be subject to ongoing variation which dances around a basically periodic occurrence, or it may be subject to gradual accretion (where not all occurrences in the series are known at the outset).
The problem with computer applications of this kind (and their algorithms and data structures) that cope with all possible needs, is that they become conceptually very complicated and difficult for users with any specific needs to learn.
They may also be relatively inefficient in how they store data, if allowance is made for every possible need, rather than what a particular user actually needs.
Bottom line is, you'll usually need to analyse your particular application and determine matching data structures in a way that employs your professional skill as a developer, rather than getting something off the shelf. There's usually a balance to be struck between ease of use, and total flexibility.
This is why many people continue to use paper diaries for time management, because it avoids the rigidity that comes with a computerisation, and allows people to devise an approach to storing appointment data that is only as complicated as their own immediate needs (not as complicated as the need of every person, in every company, in every job, in every year of living memory).
